# establised connection was aborted

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, bluestacks

Bluestacks is connected with eclipse as as emulator. But when I run any code first it gives me option to chose the device. after that it takes some times and give this error lots off times .It says that as established connection aborted. [image]

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks was developed to run android apps on windows/mac OS. Its hardly good enough for app development. I'd recommend you to use either the default emulator or [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). Genymotion is the fastest emulator for android app development yet and runs even faster than the real devices.